# Python DTMF Encoder - Ignore Special Characters

Tags: python, audio, dtmf

I want to ignore the special characters that the user inputs in a string, while outputting the DTMF signal sound.

Basically, I am building a DTMF encoder, which for each keypress of a telephone keypad, the system combines a row tone and a column tone and sends both.

For example: "12  34aB-cd$%^&76" should output the tones for "1234abcd76" ignoring spaces and all other characters not found on phone keypad. Is there any quicker and/or easier way to do this?

**Code:**

```
userInput = "12  34aB-cd$%^&76"

length = len(userInput)

sound = []

index = 0

time = 0.3
delayTime = 0.1

Fs = 8000

runningTime = np.linspace(0,time,time*Fs+1)
time2 = np.linspace(0, delayTime, delayTime*Fs+1)

lofreq = 0
hifreq = 0
totalfreq = 0

delay = np.sin(2*np.pi*20000*delayTime)

while index < length: 

if userInput[index] == 1:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*697*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1209*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 2:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*697*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1336*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 3:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*697*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1447*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 'A' or 'a':
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*697*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1633*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 4:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*770*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1209*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 5:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*770*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1336*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 6:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*770*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1447*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 'B' or 'b':
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*770*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1633*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 7:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*852*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1209*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 8:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*852*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1336*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 9:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*852*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1477*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 'C' or 'c':
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*852*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1633*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == '*':
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*941*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1209*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 0:
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*941*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1336*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == '#':
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*941*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1447*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

elif userInput[index] == 'D' or 'd':
    lofreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*941*runningTime) 
    hifreq = np.sin(2*np.pi*1633*runningTime)
    totalfreq = lofreq + hifreq
    sound.append(lofreq + hifreq)
    sound.append(delay)

index = index + 1
```

sound_out = np.concatenate(sound)

print(sound_out)

Audio(sound_out,rate = Fs)

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of acceptable characters e.g.

```
chars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]
```

and implement a condition in your code that checks if each character is not in this list. If the character is not in this list you can be sure it is unwanted in your output.